# Reusing WPF styles - changing a child property

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, wpf-4.0

I've got an `Expander` style defined as follows:

```
<Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
    <Setter ... />
    <!-- More setters -->

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
                <Border>
                    <DockPanel>
                        <ToggleButton x:Name="ChangeStyleHere" ... />
                        <Border ... />
                    </DockPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I'd like to create an identical style, but change the `Style` property of the inner `ToggleButton`.

Can I do this without duplicating the style definition? Should I use the `BasedOn` property?

Comment: Did you try the basedon property? If you did, did it work?

Comment: I've added an answer with my current approach, it works but I wonder if there is a better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the control is your own, i would always add a new dependency property for the style, template etc. For example if you have a custom ItemsControl, where the template contains a ScrollViewer, i would add a dependency property `ScrollViewerStyle`. If it isn't your control or one of the basic controls, you can always use attached properties for that. Something like

```
<TextBox myNs:TextBoxStyle.ScrollViewerStyle="{StaticResource myScrollViewer}"/>
```

`TextBoxStyle` is just a simple class with one attached property called `ScrollViewerStyle`. And of course your applied style and template must make use of this attached property. But after that you can easily change it on any TextBox.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my current approach, I wonder if there is a better way:

```
<Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
    <Setter ... />
    <!-- More setters -->

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
                <Border>
                    <DockPanel>
                        <ToggleButton x:Name="ChangeStyleHere" Style="{DynamicResource InnerStyle}" />
                        <Border ... />
                    </DockPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="DerivedStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Expander}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyStyle}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style x:Name="InnerStyle" ... />
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```